# Typescript Error for a a function that takes multiple List Types - value does not exist on interface

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-typings

I have the following interfaces as defined as below, a base interface and 2 other interfaces that extend this base one with children as properties in them.  :-

Please note that one interface has 'valueType' and other has 'returnType'

```
interface IBase {
  id:string;
  label:string;
  value:string;
  expanded:boolean;
  isGroup:boolean;
}

interface IFieldDefinitions extends IBase {
  children: Array<IFiedValues>;
}

interface ICustomFunctions extends IBase{
  children: Array<ICustomFunction & {id:string;label:string;value:string;}>
}

interface ICustomFunction{
  name:string;
  args: Array<IFunctionArgs>;
  returnType: string;
  description: string;
  array: boolean;
}

interface IFiedDefValues {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  value: string;
  label: string;
  valueType: string;
  columnType: string;
  description: string;
}
```

Now I have a simple function to group the customFunctions and fieldDefinitions based on their returType/valueType. First I've written separate functions for this grouping and realized that both the grouping functions are similar. So I wanted to create one single function which accepts the List of items and returns the grouped items, something as below.

```
public get groupFieldsByType(){
      return computeGrouping(fields,"fields");
}

public get groupFunctionsByType(){
     return computeGrouping(functions,"functions");
 }
```

Function Definition :-

```
function computeGrouping(listItems:IFieldDefinitions[] | ICustomFunctions[],type:string  ){
    
      let modifiedFieldDefs = [] as IFieldListboxItem[];
      listItems.forEach(items => {
  
       const filteredStringValues = items.children.filter(item => type === 'fields' ? item.valueType === 'Text' : item.returnType === 'String');
       const filteredNumericValues = items.children.filter(item => type === 'fields' item.valueType === 'Number' : item.returnType === 'Number');

    // other computations go in here and I return the grouped array;

     return modifiedFieldDefs;
}

 }
```

Now as you can see above, depending on the type I pass I check for either the valueType or the returnType.

Typescript is throwing me an error that

```
- "valueType" is not available on ICustomFunctions and "returnType" is not available on IFieldDefinitions
```

Please note that one interface has 'valueType' and other has 'returnType'

How can I define the interfaces and access it in the function in a way that typescript doesn't throw me this error.

Answer (score 0):

You could cast `item`:

```
function computeGrouping(listItems:IFieldDefinitions[] | ICustomFunctions[],type:string  ){
    
    let modifiedFieldDefs = [] as IFieldListboxItem[];
    listItems.forEach(items => {
  
        const filteredStringValues = items.children.filter(item => type === 'fields' ? (item as IFiedDefValues).valueType === 'Text' : (item as ICustomFunction).returnType === 'String');
        const filteredNumericValues = items.children.filter(item => type === 'fields' ? (item as IFiedDefValues).valueType === 'Number' : (item as ICustomFunction).returnType === 'Number');

    });
    return modifiedFieldDefs;
}
```